# Zend - getting all logged users

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth

I am working on Zend Framework. I have a problem with `Zend_Auth`.

I must get all logged users. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean, all currently logged in and authenticated users?

Answer (score 5):

That is outside the scope of Zend_Auth's direct scope. You'll have to code that into your application yourself.

You can easily do this after you've received a result from the authenticate() method. Once you verify that you have a valid result, you can keep track of the currently-logged-in users in a database table, or in another persistent storage system. You'll want to make sure you give a login a reasonable expiration in case someone leaves your application without actually hitting your logout method(s).